# update attributes working even if it is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a reset password page in which user has to fill password and password confirmation but even if he not fills and click on submit it he is  redirect to the   page .Also my 2nd error is if the user fills only confirm password and skip the password field still he is redirected to the page .I don't understand why @user.update_attributes not working properly.
[user.rb]

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :password
end
```

[users_controller]

```
def change_password    
    @user = User.find_by(reset_password_token: params[:users_reset_password_path][:token])    

    if @user.update_attributes(:name => @user.name,:email => @user.email,:status => @user.status, :password => params[:users_reset_password_path][:password],:password_confirmation => params[:users_reset_password_path][:password_confirmation])  
      flash[:notice] = "password successfully updated"
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      @token = @user.reset_password_token 
      render  users_reset_password_path
    end
end
```

[users/_reset_password.html.erb]

```
    <div id="nav-col-submenu"></div>
      </div>

        <div id="content-wrapper">


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class=" clearfix">

              <div id="login-box">
          <%= render :partial => "shared/error_messages", :locals => { :errors => @user.errors } %>
          <div id="login-box-holder">

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <header id="login-header">
                  <div id="login-logo">
                    <img src="/assets/gionee_logo1.png" alt=""/>
                  </div>
                </header>
          <div id="login-box-inner">
        <%= form_for :users_reset_password_path  do |f| %>

                    <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
          <%= f.password_field :password,class: "form-control",placeholder: "Password" %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>
          <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation,class: "form-control",placeholder: "Confirm Password" %>
                    </div>

           <%= f.hidden_field :token ,value: if params[:token] != nil then params[:token] else @token end%>

                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-12">
          <%= f.submit "Reset Password",class: "btn btn-success col-xs-12" %> 

                      </div>
                    </div>

                  <% end %>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



        </div>


              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

  <%= render 'page_js/user_search'%>
```

Comment: [validates_presence_of](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_presence_of).

Comment: i have to use validates _presence_of instead of validates_confirmation_of?

Comment: `"but even if he not fills and click on submit it he is redirect to the page".` For this you should check for presence.

Comment: I have change validation_confirmation_of to validate_presence_of  still not working

Comment: I don't see you have used `validate_presence_of`. You are checking `validates_confirmation_of` only if password is present.

Comment: okay let me update my question with the answer you provided

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
```